# Firebase admin SDK getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, nestjs

I'm trying to set up the admin sdk and also created a new private key. I even reverted back to an old version with only the admin sdk and it won't work. Is there anything which could be cached on my device?

```
Nest application successfully started NestApplication true
Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND". Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND".
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/user/Documents/Dev/project/demo/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/user/Documents/Dev/project/demo/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/Users/user/Documents/Dev/project/demo/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
    at /Users/user/Documents/Dev/project/demo/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:121:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
    at /Users/user/Documents/Dev/project/demo/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:44:28
    at /Users/user/Documents/Dev/project/demo/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:8:17 ExceptionsHandler
```

This is how I'm trying to use both packages:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import * as serviceAccount from '../../firebase_credentials.json';

const config = {
    type: serviceAccount.type,
    projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
    privateKeyId: serviceAccount.private_key_id,
    privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key,
    clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
    clientId: serviceAccount.client_id,
    authUri: serviceAccount.auth_uri,
    tokenUri: serviceAccount.token_uri,
    authProviderX509CertUrl: serviceAccount.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
    clientC509CertUrl: serviceAccount.client_x509_cert_url,
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth();

export function create(email: string, password: string) {
    firebaseAuth.createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: password,
        displayName: email,
        disabled: false,
    })
        .then( (userRecord) => {
            // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
            console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
        });

}
```

What should I try to get this resolved?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both the Admin SDK and the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK in a single application. If the app runs in a potentially untrusted environment, you should use the regular JavaScript SDK. If it runs in a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions) you can use either the JavaScript SDK or the Admin SDK for that environment (in your case for Node.js).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to revert to an old version where I only used the admin SDK. I get the same error as before. Any idea why? (Updated initial post)

Comment: That is a different problem. Please don't edit your question to change its meaning after people have responded, as right now my answer above makes no sense anymore. If you have a different problem with your older code that addresses my answer, open a new question for that problem.